# Kraken API: 400 Bad Request when making AddOrder request using Boost.Beast

Tags: c++, rest, client, boost-asio, boost-beast

I am trying to make a request to the Kraken API's AddOrder endpoint using Boost.Beast in C++.

This is the endpoint I am trying to access : https://docs.kraken.com/rest/#tag/User-Trading/operation/addOrder

I am encoding the request body and passing it to the req_.body() method, but I am still getting a 400 Bad Request error.

Here is the request body and encoded request body I am passing:

request body:

```
nonce=1419646086&ordertype=limit&pair=XBTUSD&price=25000.000000&type=buy&volume=1.000000
```

Encoded request body which is passed to req_.body():

```
nonce%3D1419646086%26ordertype%3Dlimit%26pair%3DXBTUSD%26price%3D25000.000000%26type%3Dbuy%26volume%3D1.000000
```

The url.string() Outputs this which is the correct endpoint :

```
https://api.kraken.com/0/private/AddOrder
```

Here is the raw request and response:

```
raw request:
POST /0/private/AddOrder HTTP/1.1
API-Sign: vMP6JwOHe4nA+hnOfDSMEOUmMmZ2UK9RCk9gpRfYOONXhxZW2/QUrDslZCELJo9/cNJlVyBvC4texDk49fwE6g==
Host: api.kraken.com
User-Agent: Boost.Beast/330
API-Key: Skz2FPOvhvvYrOHi6qMEqmmz
```

Response :

```
raw response : HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: cloudflare
Date: Tue, 27 Dec 2022 17:25:24 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 155
Connection: close
CF-RAY: -

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>cloudflare</center>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I have included all the necessary headers and properly signed the message (I have verified it in postman and it works).

This is my code using the examples provided in the boost.beast :
https://gist.github.com/Naseefabu/0f2315ec9727c3e0821ff941a5b370ce

Comment: I don't see the response. In fact I don't see the full request. What does the response look like (in full) and how does it compare with the postman version?

Comment: Also I hope that's not a live key/secret combination. Please remove gist if not

Comment: updated with response. Yes its not real! In the postman its sends the valid json as response containing the message "EAPI:Invalid key" (which is the message sent by the exchange, i should be getting like this one in my C++ code as well ? instead of getting 400 Bad Request ?).

Comment: If you need me to print anything to the console please lmk @sehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just chipping away at issues in the code. Your nonce generates a string, which you then convert to a long, but store in an int32 variable. Only to then convert it back to a string. I'd cut the whole mess and avoid truncation issues by using

```
long generate_nonce() {
    return std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch() / 1ms;
}
```

Note how much simpler and more efficient that is. Also, how much more correct, as you can see that `int32` fatally corrupts the value: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce30cbd6ec5b089e

That's just the first thing that I looked at, and it becomes way more complex from here. I'm not at convinced that you generate the postdata for signing correctly:

- you're using a `std::map` which affects the ordering
- you're not using the encoded data - which is likely what you should be doing, since different valid encodings exist for URLs and the server would probably **first** validate the signature **before** trying to interpret the parts (for security reasons).
- when building urls, prefer to use the library instead of manual string manipulation
- nowhere do I see the `nonce=` part in the postdata (maybe I'm overlooking it in the mild spaghetti), but I see it e.g. [here](https://github.com/voidloop/krakenapi/blob/master/kapi.cpp#L267)

I'll probably keep looking for a bit, but this should get you started.

### Update

I spotted another issue:

```
std::vector<char> sigdigest_b64(2 * sigdigest_len);
EVP_EncodeBlock((unsigned char*)sigdigest_b64.data(), sigdigest, sigdigest_len);

return std::string(sigdigest_b64.data(), sigdigest_b64.size());
```

Neither the length approximation nor the ignored return value inspire confidence. I'd expect

```
std::string sigdigest_b64(1 + 4 * (1 + sigdigest_len / 3), '\0');
auto        sigdigest_b64_len = EVP_EncodeBlock(
    reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(sigdigest_b64.data()), sigdigest, sigdigest_len);
sigdigest_b64.resize(sigdigest_b64_len);

return sigdigest_b64;
```

Or better yet,

```
// Encode the signature in base64.
return base64_encode({sigdigest, sigdigest_len});
```

With a suitable helper function that you might not even reimplement yourself:

```
std::string base64_encode(std::basic_string_view<unsigned char> payload) {
    std::string result(1 + 4 * (1 + payload.size() / 3), '\0');
    auto        n = EVP_EncodeBlock(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(result.data()),
                                    payload.data(), payload.size());
    result.resize(n);
    return result;
}
```

Then, have unit tests with that implementation :)

Comment: By the way, you could have trivially spotted the nonce being wrong when you compare the *actual* postman request and the beast one closely. You will see other things as well. I'll stop, because I just saw another big issue which I'll add the the answer text, but continuing without actual side-by-side is considerably more effort than required, so I encourage you to do that part :)

Comment: i am getting this now : {"error":["EGeneral:Internal error"]}
is it server error and not mine ?
https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000898063-Kraken-Terminal-trading-interface-errors#:~:text=Internal%20errors%20usually%20mean%20the%20issue%20occurred%20on%20our%20end.&text=What%20you%20can%20do%3A%20Monitor,persists%2C%20wait%20and%20try%20again.

Comment: Again, we have zero information to go by. What is the HTTP status code? If it's 5xx then yes, I'd assume server error. If not, assume client error.  If you are stuck and think you solved all the issues of which I pointed out parts, please post a new question *with self-contained example to reproduce*